# Handle XMLHttpRequest .NET

Tags: .net, xmlhttprequest, handle

Can anyone tell me how can i retrieve data on my web service written in .NET.
I have posted my data through XML HTTP Request.
Data has successfully posted as it returns readyState as 4.
But i dont know how to access the data on the service so that i can do manipulation on that data.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to write a client program to access your service? Will the client also be written in .NET? Why do you mention XmlHttpRequest? It is not used in creating either clients or services in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to handle it through an ASHX file or something other than a web service.  The web service code in .net is looking for specific SOAP requests, and unless it is found, the service won't respond.

In an ASHX (or aspx etc).  You can use Request.Form to get the posted values you need.

If you have written the service, you can make a "proxy" for it in the form of an ASHX.  Have the ASHX file take the values out of the XmlHTTPPost, open a web service connection and submit the information to the web service like you would in a normal web service communication.

Comment: Kevin, this depends on what he's looking for. He seems to be saying he's already written the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending POX over HTTP, then you will probably want a "handler" approach, that reads from the `context.Request.InputStream`, and writes to `context.Response.OutputStream` - simply using anything like `XDocument.Load` / `XmlDocument.Load`.